# How to do a bash shell for with increment with a variable 0 number as first character

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How to do a bash shell for with increment with 0 as first character for increment like :

```
for (( c=1; c<=75; c++ )) ; do echo 0$c ; done ;
```

gives me that :

```
.../...
07
08
09
010
011
.../...
```

My problem i would get a double 00 for the 9 first digit, so I would like this result as issue :

```
.../...
007
008
009
010
011
.../...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [Arkadiusz Drabczyk](https://superuser.com/users/328038/arkadiusz-drabczyk)'s answer formats the output as you want, there is another approach:-

```
for c in {01..75}; do echo $c; done;   # for two digits
for c in {001..075}; do echo $c; done; # for three digits
```

This includes leading zeroes in the assigned values of `c`, as opposed to adding them when output, and I can imagine circumstances where this would be more useful.

Comment: Right but you have to write the echo command like this `echo 0$c`

Comment: What do you mean by `or it would if he'd use %02d`? OP explicitly wanted `001`, `002` etc.

Comment: @dubis then do `{001..075}`, it's more elegant then `echo 0$c`

Comment: or `printf "%s\n" {001..075}`. Anyway, using leading zeroes in a brace expansion requires a new enough Bash

Comment: @ilkkachu Which you **MUST** have anyway! ([Shellshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)), anyone?)

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. It outputs `07`, `08` etc not `007`, `008` as the OP requested.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk - @DavidPostill - I was rushing to get out, and it was not at all clear that he wanted 3 digits, since he appeared to say `009` was a problem, but I apologise for the comment about `%02d`, which I've removed. Having now understood what the questioner wanted, I have amended my answer. It was never my intention to displace Arkadiusz Drabczyk's already accepted answer.

Comment: Two more ways to skin that cat :) `seq -f '%03.0f' 7 11` `seq -w 7 11|xargs -I{} echo 0{}`

Comment: No need of xargs.  `seq -w 7 011` `seq -w 007 11`

Comment: @Paulo - two points about your solution: (1) `seq` (and `xargs`) are external programs, which is an overhead best avoided if it's possible with `bash` internals, like `for` and `printf`; (2) just printing numbers in a particular format is not terribly useful in itself, and both my answer and Arkadiusz Drabczyk's assign a variable that more can be done with. That said, your answers undoubtedly work, and may suggest other uses for the techniques.

Comment: @AFH I agree with avoid overhead with external programs if one can do the task only with shell builtins, in this case bash. I posted the `seq` solutions because I know the -f and -w options, but I didn't know the construction of my second comment, that was new for me.

Comment: @Paulo - Curiously, I found that you can use analogous expressions if you use a range: `{001..075}`, `{1..075}` and `{001..75}` are all equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

Using `printf` like this:

```
for (( c=1; c<=75; c++ )) ; do printf "%03d\n" "$c" ; done
```